# How to randomly pick a value based on the position of the bit

Tags: c, arrays, random, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Is there a way to pick a value based on the bit position. The problem statement is:-
for a 16 bits position, I can set any bits, say I set 1,4,6,7,11,13 bit
so the mask would be:-

```
Bit Positons 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Now I need to randomly pick a value based on this bit mask, where only 1 bit is set, so my possible values could be:-

For selecting 4 :0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

`For Selecting 7: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

But I need to select this value randomly, so I though of doing it like this

1)Create an Array based on the bit mask, so for 16 bit , the array would have 16 unique values.

2) Now do the rand operation on the array position to get the array index.

3) Use the value at that array index.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: When you have randomly picked a value, should the result be a value with _exactly_ one bit set, or with _at most_ one bit set?

Comment: With exactly 1 bit set, which is also set in bitmask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a number with exactly one bit set that is also set in the mask.

To do this I'd make a while loop that selects a random value between 0 and 16 until it has found one that is also set in the mask:

```
uint16_t mask = 0x28d2; /* == 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 */
int bit = 0;

do{
    bit = 1 << (rand() % 16); /* sets one random bit between 1 and 16 */
}while(!(mask & bit)); 

/* bit has now exactly one bit set that is also set in mask */
```

Comment: But in that case, if I want to expand it to 64 bit, it will be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have a value with at most one bit set at the end, you don't need the array. You can simply randomly generate a value between 0-15, then bitshift 1 left by that value to get the mask that you will use to select the bit, like this:

```
uint16_t myValue = 0xA5;
int shiftValue = rand() % 16;
uint16_t randomMask = 1u << shiftValue;
uint16_t randomValue = myValue & randomMask;
```

If you instead need a value with exactly one of the bits set at the end, it gets a little trickier. At that point, you could do more or less what you said and use an array to store the positions of the bits that are set (e.g. `[1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, using zeroes to indicate when there are no more bits set), then generate a random index into the portion of the array containing valid indices. There are certainly other ways to do it too, but this way seems like one that will be fairly clear to future readers of the code (though I would still comment this somewhat carefully, since bit operations can get confusing fast).

(BTW, there are much better ways of generating random numbers than `rand()`, and you should probably use one of those if you need anything approaching real randomness - I just used it here as a convenient shorthand, since the actual RNG doesn't matter.)

Comment: Well, The objective is to have a better way to generate a random index in the array of the Possible values, so if I have 28 bits set in bitmask, then I can put those 28 possible values in an array and then I can randomly generate an index to that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way:

```
bitMask = 0x28d2;

randomNum = rand() % 16;
randomBit = (1<<randomNum) & bitMask;
```

Comment: This will not return Value, with only 1 bit set from the mask.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *exactly* one bit set, you could use a re-try loop, or something like this: (add the appropriate definitions and maybe add a special case for `mask == 0`)

```
while (mask)
{
    array[i++] = mask & -mask;
    mask &= mask - 1;
}
return array[rand_in_range(0, i)];
```

Where `rand_in_range(a, b)` is a function that returns a random number in the range [a, b> (be careful with that, 99% of the implementations of `rand_in_range` are incorrect *while seeming correct in most tests*, the worst kind of bug).